# Function inside document ready JQuery can't be called from JS(Outside)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
  testFunction(){
   //do some hard work~   
   }
});
testFunction(); //not working
<script/>
```

I'm trying to call testFunction which is inside the JQuery, but it's not working. Following error is occuring: **testFunction is not defined**

Comment: Why are you defining it inside, yet calling it outside of `ready()`? The opposite would make more sense.

Comment: Actually there are some dependecies, it has to be inside the document.ready()

Comment: The issue is not only the scope, which could be solved, but also the order of execution. `ready()` executes after you are inovking `testFunction()`. If it has dependencies which require it to be inside `ready()`, I see no reason to invoke it before/outside of it. Just put  `testFunction();` inside `ready()` as well.

Comment: The technical issue is [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#JavaScript) - your function is defined *inside* another function so is not available from outside of it.   Defining a *function* inside doc.ready makes little sense unless you want it to be only available inside the doc.ready.   It's likely the "dependencies" are not relevant to where the function is *defined* but rather **when** it is *called* / executed.   Would be interesting to see what these dependencies are if you could add a sample.

Comment: The DOM most like since it requires ready.

Comment: @JavaScript most likely, in which case the function *definition* does *not* need to be in doc.ready